# Binding a second vertex buffer seems to spoil my first vertex buffer, OpenGL OES ios 5.1

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-buffer

I'm creating two different vertex buffers, *that use two different shaders to render them*.  As soon as I bind the second vertex buffer, the data I parked in the first vertex buffer seems to be corrupted or lost.

If I generate and draw one vertex buffer only, like so:

```
glGenBuffers( 1, &vb1 ) ;
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb1 ) ;

// fill it..
glBufferData( .. )
```

Then, in the draw() loop,

```
glUseProgram( shader1 ) ;
glBindBuffer( vb1 ) ; // make sure it is bound
glDrawArrays( ... )   // draw it
```

Then it works fine, no problems, no errors (I am glGettingLastError() after *every* gl* call, so it seems this code is perfectly fine)

Now if I so much as *generate and bind* a second vertex buffer, any time after the first one was generated and bound,

```
// ran in init() -- then previously working code in draw() is broken
glGenBuffers( 1, &vb2 ) ;              // ok.. no problems with this line
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb2 ) ; // spoils data in vb1?
```

As soon as I call `glBindBuffer` with this newly generated `vb2` buffer, it seems the data in `vb1` is completely dumped or lost. On attempts to draw `vb1` (not `vb2`!), i get this crash:

[image]

I even filled the array with `GL_STATIC_DRAW`.

I don't understand, I thought these vertex buffers were supposed to retain data, even if another vertex buffer is created and initialized?  .. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *what am I doing wrong?* It's hard to say, considering that you've provided so little code, and the code you have put up is non-functional (binding a buffer has no effect on DrawArrays, only setting pointers controls what data is drawn). Can you show what you're actually doing?

Comment: Admittedly, this isn't a very good question.  I'll delete it.

Comment: We're locked out of Meta at the moment, but I undeleted this question for you, so you're good to edit it now.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this question to be very subtle and difficult to find.

I thought I didn't need [the vertex array declarations that the standard example uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428473/in-the-stock-opengl-es-app-on-ios-5-1-are-they-really-using-the-vertex-arrays-t), and you can see I left them out in the question.  But it turns out using [vertex array objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429065/111307) is vital to correctly binding indices.

So for example,

```
// Make vertex array OBJECT, _this does not store any data!_
// A "vertex array object" is a bit like a display list in
// that it will just remember and repeat the function calls you make,
// with the values you make them with.
glGenVertexArraysOES( 1, &va ) ; // make vertex array OBJECT. NOT used
// to store data..

// Bind the vertex array
glBindVertexArrayOES( va ) ; // "start recording the calls I make.."

// Make a buffer for the vertex array (place to store the data)
glGenBuffers( 1, &vb ) ;     // make the vertex BUFFER (used to
// store the actual data)

// Make the vertex array buffer active
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb ) ;

glEnableVertexAttribArray( ... ) ;  // REMEMBERED IN VAO (vertex array object)
glVertexAttribPointer( ... ) ;      // REMEMBERED IN VAO

glBufferData( .. ) ; // send data down to gpu, not remembered by vao

// "Stop remembering" calls to glBindBuffer( .. ) and glEnableVertexAttribArray( .. )
glBindVertexArrayOES( 0 ) ; // "stop recording"
```

At draw time, simply:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES( va ) ; // runs ALL your glEnableVertexAttribArray() calls,
// as well as your glBindBuffer( .. ) call,

// now all that's left to do is draw
glDrawArrays( glDrawingStyle, 0, vertexCount );
```